# problems while tying to load a image in Laravel with <img src={{route()}}

Tags: php, laravel

greeting to the community...so I´m developping a little compact pplication with Laravel. The problem is that I´m trying to load the image from the folder Storage, "Storage/Pets", I tried successfully with another controller, but this time..and I dont know what a fu..I´m doing wrong, It seems that the pic is not found,(although I get the file name from MySql) becouse I don´t receive warns from Laravel.. I´ll appreciate any help..any help is welcome..:))

I try to do my best with the explanation...

the Controller

[image]

The function to load the image

[image]

The routes

[image]

The View pet.blade.php

[image]

If it is needed I can add even more "screenshots", the lat one is the code from ctrl+U where the route path is available...

[image]

Comment: Do not post your code as images... Code is text, please copy and paste it into your question, and format it.

Comment: what response are you getting from the server 200, 500 ?

Comment: Have you tried passing the header in the second parameter of your response?

Comment: Hi lagbox        thanks for your reply. Well! in the console I see :Error: request failed with status 404, while in the "network", I see 200. I supose becouse my object "Pet" is comming ok from the controller...:))

Comment: Hi also Darick...I really dont undertsnd you..you mean add a second parameter to my getImage($filename){}   ????  :))

Comment: in your last image you have click one of those links to the image source and see what the network tab says about it

Comment: Hi lagbox, thats what I get after ctrl+u and click on the link: rror: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Response' not found in file C:\wamp64\www\proyectos_Laravel\petcare_service\app\Http\Controllers\PetController.php on line 71
the line 71 refers to :  return new Response($file,200); from the controller method...:)

Comment: can you try using return response()->file($pathToFile); instead

Answer (score 2):

You should always try to post code as text, as it is text not images.

Now that you have figured out how to get the error for the requests that aren't working you can fix the issue.

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Response' not found in file C:\wamp64\www\proyectos_Laravel\petcare_service\app\Http\Controllers\PetController.php on line 71

You didn't alias the `Response` class in your Controller:

```
use Response;
// or
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
```

Or (as mentioned in the comments) you can use the helper function instead of the facade:

```
response()
```

Comment: It Works!!!!!!!!! lord bless stackoverflow!!!!!...thank u very much!!..I´ll try to follow your advice next time I post some question.!! Greetings!!!:)))))